# Accessing Environment Variables in a linked Docker

Tags: docker

How do I access the environment variables of a source container from another container which is linking to it with the `--link` argument?
The docker manual states:

> **Environment Variables**
>
> Docker creates several environment variables when you link containers.
>   Docker automatically creates environment variables in the target
>   container based on the `--link` parameters. It will also expose all
>   environment variables originating from Docker from the source
>   container. These include variables from:
>
> - the `ENV` commands in the source container's Dockerfile
> - the `-e`, `--env` and `--env-file` options on the `docker run` command when the source container is started
>
> http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

But I can't access an environment variable which I set with

```
ENV MY_VARIABLE = "example"
```

in the linking container with

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $MY_VARIABLE
```

it will contain no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables from the source container are prefixed with the alias set with the `--link <source container>:<alias>` in the target container:

```
$<alias>_ENV_<env variable>
```

The environment variable will be accessible as follows if `<alias>` is e.g. set to `source`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $SOURCE_ENV_MY_VARIABLE
```